# Zero_Division_Error I think there is no 0 at denominator and numarator

Tags: python

It is constantly showing the error that ZeroDivisionError.

```
start= 11
end = 75
print("Prime numbers between ",start," and ",end," are : ")
for i in range (start, end+1):
  if i > 1:
    c = 2*i
    for j in range(c):
      if i//j == 0:
        break
      else:
        print(i)
```

Comment: change `for j in range(c)` to `for j in range(2, c)`

Answer (score 0):

`range(c)` specifies that the loop should start at 0.
`range(1,c)` specifies that the loop should start at 1.

Answer (score 0):

You get the error because in python, when you use `for loop`, it iterates from 0 to c, and since you're making a division (i // j), you're dividing by `0` in the first loop iteration.

Here is how it should be done:

```py
start= 11
end = 75
print("Prime numbers between ",start," and ",end," are : ")
for i in range (start, end+1):
  if i > 1:
    c = 2*i
    for j in range(1, c): #we're iterating now from 1 to c
      if i//j == 0:
        break
      else:
        print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

`range(c)` is 0 all the way to c

solution: `range(1,c)`